# Command Prompt: TAKEOWN, ICACLS and Wildcards

Tags: windows-7, cmd.exe

I need to take ownership of some files and folders.
I know which commands to use but I also need wildcards and this doesn't work:

TAKEOWN /f *wildcard* /r /d y

It works if I use, for example, *wildcard* with DEL command but it doesn't with TAKEOWN or ICACLS.

Why?

Note.
You have to imagine the asterisks before and after the word wildcard, because they're not visualized on Superuser... lol.

[x]wildcard[x]

I mean this:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? The `/f` switch on `takeown` does accept wildcards, as does `icacls`.

Comment: You're using `*` right? If so, that should be working fine.

Comment: Maybe you mean wildcard.ext or filename.wildcard.

Comment: I need wildcard between two asterisks and Microsoft says invalid aurgument.

Comment: I added an image; now it's more clear...

Comment: There's nothing on Technet that says I can't do it... It only says I can't use asterisk + question mark; but with Microsoft nothing can be done easily... everything has to be painful...

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, I solved my problem.
I used wildcard (between two asterisks) like in DEL command, but with TAKEOWN is different (ask Microsoft...).
This is the correct syntax:

TAKEOWN /f Windows\winsxs\[x]wildcard[x] /r /d y

Takeown requires the complete path + wildcard.
It is not recursive.

Comment: If you write only the wildcard (like in DEL command) it doesn't work.